# How to read data from FireBase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have problem reading from Firebase in Swift.

Here is my Firebase database:

[image]

and here is my code:

```
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSLog("Reading from DB")

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    self.ref?.child("Frais").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Int]
        var frpx1 = (value?["frpx1"]!)!
        var frpx10 = (value?["frpx10"]!)!
        var frpx11 = (value?["frpx11"]!)!
        var frpx12 = (value?["frpx12"]!)!
        var frpx13 = (value?["frpx13"]!)!
        var frpx14 = (value?["frpx14"]!)!
        var frpx15 = (value?["frpx15"]!)!
        var frpx16 = (value?["frpx16"]!)!            
    })

    print(frpx1)
    print(frpx10)
    print(frpx11)
    print(frpx12)
    print(frpx13)
    print(frpx14)
    print(frpx15)
    print(frpx16)
}
```

I did not find the problem.

I do not have the data from database in `frpx1`, ..., `frpx16`.

Comment: Those `print` statements have no access to the local variables created inside the completion handler. Are you getting compiler errors or are there other variables (properties?) declared elsewhere with the same names?

Comment: BTW - do not ignore any wearings. Your code should compile clean.

Comment: print is only to control the value inside each variable

Answer (score 0):

Your code have a couple of minor issues:

- you are *casting* the returned value to `[String: Int]` when you should be using `[String: Any]` instead since not all values are `String` based.
- you are printing the results *outside* the completion handler. You need to wait the handler to be called to then read the results (i.e., when the method `observeSingleEvent` returns Firebase is still processing your request).

Fixing both issues should get you going:

```
...
self.ref?.child("Frais").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { 
    (snapshot) in
    guard let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
        print("Snapshot type mismatch: \(snapshot.key)")
        return
    }
    let frpx1  = value["frpx1"]
    let frpx10 = value["frpx10"]
    let frpx11 = value["frpx11"]
    ... 
    print(frpx1)
    print(frpx10)
    print(frpx11)
    ...
})
```

PS. I also improved your coding style a little to help prevent further issues ;)

Comment: When I correct your code,... I have an error. But why do he say "ambiguous use of ' observeSingleEvent ' " on the line ---->   self.ref?.child("Frais").observeSingleEvent(of: .value).  <----      I have try to change snapshot to snapshot2 because I have in the app another snapshot on another page. It is to have no confusion between the 2 snapshot